# No module name books

Tags: python, django, traceback

i'm having the following error in my python server, using django.

```
C:\Users\Nuno\Favorites\Desktop\Django\mysiteproject>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x03180B70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 252, in
raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in pop
ulate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in
 ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24
, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 74,
in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Nuno\Favorites\Desktop\Django\mysiteproject\books\admin.py", li
ne 4, in <module>
    from mysiteproject.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
ImportError: No module named books.models
```

The structure of my project is the following:

```
Django
   books
      migrations
           __init__.py
           0001_initial.py
      __init__.py
      admin.py
      models.py
      tests.py
      views.py
   mysiteproject
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
      views.py 
      templates 
          base.html
          current_datetime.html
          hours_ahead.html    
   books.db
   manage.py
```

Does someone has a clue on what am i doing wrong?
python version: 1.7.9
Django version: 1.8.4

Comment: Loos like a PYTHONPATH problem. If it points to your project directory, you might have to remove the `mysiteproject.` from the import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your import code:

```
from mysiteproject.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
```

to;

```
from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
```

Comment: So simple, thanks! That's what i get from copy paste.